# having issues with javascript style properties of an html element

Tags: javascript, css, styles, element

I am trying to change the style property which is set in the inline in the HTML. I'm using clickfunnels as my landing page builder and I can only add CSS rules.

My issue is that when you view the site on mobile there is extra empty space to the right of the page (see screenshot).

I troubleshooted it in the console to find out that if I manually change the property of the `overflow` to `auto` it solves the issue.

Since then I've tried to add various type of custom css (disclaimer I'm not familiar with this) but with no success.

What I've tried to add to the css:

```
html.style.property={overflow:auto;}
#html.style.property={overflow:auto;}
.html.style.property={overflow:auto;}
grammarly-btn {display:none!important;}
#html{overflow:auto;}
#clickfunnels-com{overflow:auto;}
#wf-proximanova-i4-active{overflow:auto;}
#wf-proximanova-i7-active{overflow:auto;}
#wf-proximanova-n4-active{overflow:auto;}
#wf-proximanova-n7-active{overflow:auto;}
#wf-active{overflow:auto;}
#wf-proximanova-i3-active{overflow:auto;}
#wf-proximanova-n3-active{overflow:auto;}
#elFont_opensans{overflow:auto;}
#wf-proximanovasoft-n4-active{overflow:auto;}
#wf-proximanovasoft-n7-active{overflow:auto;}
#wf-proximasoft-n4-active{overflow:auto;}
#wf-proximasoft-i4-active{overflow:auto;}
#wf-proximasoft-i6-active{overflow:auto;}
#wf-proximasoft-n6-active{overflow:auto;}
#wf-proximasoft-i7-active{overflow:auto;}
#wf-proximasoft-n7-active{overflow:auto;}
#bgRepeat{overflow:auto;}
#avcHn2VQJenBvoR5hilPG{overflow:auto;}

getElementByID.html{overflow:auto;}
getElementByID.html='overflow:auto';
```

The element in the source view is this:

```
<html lang="en" class="clickfunnels-com wf-proximanova-i4-active wf-proximanova-i7-active wf-proximanova-n4-active wf-proximanova-n7-active wf-active wf-proximanova-i3-active wf-proximanova-n3-active elFont_opensans wf-proximanovasoft-n4-active wf-proximanovasoft-n7-active wf-proximasoft-n4-active wf-proximasoft-i4-active wf-proximasoft-i6-active wf-proximasoft-n6-active wf-proximasoft-i7-active wf-proximasoft-n7-active bgRepeat avcHn2VQJenBvoR5hilPG " style="overflow: initial; background-color: rgb(252, 213, 213); --darkreader-inline-bgcolor:#2f251e; font-family: Lato, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;">
```

here is a screenshot better describing my issue:

[screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWdjz.png)

Comment: Where are you performing `html.style...`. It might be better to either use JavaScript to change element styles or reference an external style sheet. In the stylesheet you can set media queries which can check the screen size and device and apply different styles accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to use JavaScript to apply styles to your HTML, you need access the specific style property of your html that you are trying to change.

`getElementByID.html='overflow:auto';` won't work.

You should write something like `document.getElementbyId('your_id').style.overflow = 'auto'`

If you are just trying to select your HTML entirely then you don't need to use `getElementById` but can rather use a

`document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.overflow = 'auto'`.

Another alternative is using an external stylesheet and implementing media queries to adjust for mobile view. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) is how to add an external stylesheet.

See the snippet for an example of a media query in CSS. is some example CSS.

```css
html{
 background-color: pink;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  /* when screen is this size or smaller, background color will change */
  html {
    background-color: orange;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you It did the job! I had to use !important to override the previous style! Thank you so much

Comment: @TeodorIenkov Glad it helped! When you get a chance feel free to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

to fix your issue of white space on the right, study more about [Responsive Web Design](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp).
in general, I would put all my body in one container and set its margin to 50% of both sides.